# Data not coming from frontend issue in basic mern app

Tags: reactjs, node.js, mongodb

I was creating a basic mern app, but I encountered an issue where my frontend is not sending data to the backend.

```
frontend code:
import { useState } from 'react';

const SurveyForm = () => {
  const [name, setName] = useState('');
  const [gender, setGender] = useState('male');
  const [nationality, setNationality] = useState('');
  const [email, setEmail] = useState('');
  const [phoneNumber, setPhoneNumber] = useState('');
  const [address, setAddress] = useState('');
  const [message, setMessage] = useState('');
  const [hiddenText, setHiddenText] = useState('');

  const handleSubmit = async(e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    if (hiddenText !== '') {
      alert('Form submission appears to be spam.');
      return;
    }
    const newSurvey = {
      name,
      gender,
      nationality,
      email,
      phoneNumber,
      address,
      message
    };
    console.log(newSurvey)
    const response = await fetch(`http://localhost:5000/survey/add-survey`, {
      method: 'POST', // *GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, etc.
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
      },
      body: JSON.stringify({name,
        gender,
        nationality,
        email,
        phoneNumber,
        address,
        message})
    });
    const jsona = await response.json();
    console.log(jsona);
    setName('');
    setGender('');
    setNationality('');
    setEmail('');
    setPhoneNumber('');
    setAddress('');
    setMessage('');
 
    alert('Form submitted successfully!');
   
  }
  return (
   <div className="min-h-screen bg-gray-100 py-6 flex flex-col justify-center sm:py-12">
 <div className="relative py-3 ">
   <div className="relative  bg-white shadow-lg sm:rounded-3xl sm:p-20">
     <h1 className="text-2xl font-bold mb-8 text-center">Survey Form</h1>
     <form onSubmit={handleSubmit} className="space-y-6">
       <div>
         <label htmlFor="name" className="block text-sm font-medium text-gray-700">Name:</label>
         <input id="name" name="name" type="text" autoComplete="name" required className="mt-1 block w-full py-2 px-3 border border-gray-300 bg-white rounded-md shadow-sm focus:outline-none focus:ring-indigo-500 focus:border-indigo-500 sm:text-sm" value={name} onChange={(e) => setName(e.target.value)} />
       </div>
       <div>
         <label htmlFor="gender" className="block text-sm font-medium text-gray-700">Gender:</label>
         <select id="gender" name="gender" required className="mt-1 block w-full py-2 px-3 border border-gray-300 bg-white rounded-md shadow-sm focus:outline-none focus:ring-indigo-500 focus:border-indigo-500 sm:text-sm" value={gender} onChange={(e) => setGender(e.target.value)}>
           <option value="male">Male</option>
           <option value="female">Female</option>
           <option value="other">Other</option>
         </select>
       </div>
       <div>
         <label htmlFor="nationality" className="block text-sm font-medium text-gray-700">Nationality:</label>
         <input id="nationality" name="nationality" type="text" required className="mt-1 block w-full py-2 px-3 border border-gray-300 bg-white rounded-md shadow-sm focus:outline-none focus:ring-indigo-500 focus:border-indigo-500 sm:text-sm" value={nationality} onChange={(e) => setNationality(e.target.value)} />
       </div>
       <div>
         <label htmlFor="email" className="block text-sm font-medium text-gray-700">Email:</label>
         <input id="email" name="email" type="email" autoComplete="email" required className="mt-1 block w-full py-2 px-3 border border-gray-300 bg-white rounded-md shadow-sm focus:outline-none focus:ring-indigo-500 focus:border-indigo-500 sm:text-sm" value={email} onChange={(e) => setEmail(e.target.value)} />
       </div>
       <div>
         <label htmlFor="phoneNumber" className="block text-sm font-medium text-gray-700">Phone Number:</label>
         <input id="phoneNumber" name="phoneNumber" type="tel" required className="mt-1 block w-full py-2 px-3 border border-gray-300 bg-white rounded-md shadow-sm focus:outline-none focus:ring-indigo-500 focus:border-indigo-500 sm:text-sm" value={phoneNumber} onChange={(e) => setPhoneNumber(e.target.value)} />
       </div>
       <div>
         <label htmlFor="address" className="block text-sm font-medium text-gray-700">Address:</label>
         <textarea id="address" name="address" required className="mt-1 block w-full py-2 px-3 border border-gray-300 bg-white rounded-md shadow-sm focus:outline-none focus:ring-indigo-500 focus:border-indigo-500 sm:text-sm" value={address} onChange={(e) => setAddress(e.target.value)}></textarea>
       </div>
       <div>
         <label htmlFor="message" className="block text-sm font-medium text-gray-700">Message:</label>
         <textarea id="message" name="message" required className="mt-1 block w-full py-2 px-3 border border-gray-300 bg-white rounded-md shadow-sm focus:outline-none focus:ring-indigo-500 focus:border-indigo-500 sm:text-sm" value={message} onChange={(e) => setMessage(e.target.value)}></textarea>
       </div>
       <input type="text" value={hiddenText} onChange={(e) => setHiddenText(e.target.value)} style={{display: 'none'}} />
       <button type="submit" className="w-full flex justify-center py-2 px-4 border border-transparent rounded-md shadow-sm text-sm font-medium text-white bg-indigo-600 hover:bg-indigo-700 focus:outline-none focus:ring-2 focus:ring-offset-2 focus:ring-indigo-500">Submit</button>
     </form>
   </div>
 </div>
</div>

  );
};
```

Backend code:

```
export default SurveyForm;
backend code:
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();
const Survey = require('../models/Survey');

router.get('/get-surveys', (req, res) => {
    Survey.find({}, (err, surveys) => {
      if (err) {
        res.status(500).send('Error retrieving surveys');
      } else {
        res.status(200).json(surveys);
      }
    });
  });


router.post('/add-survey', async (req, res) => {
    const surveyData = req.body;
    console.log(surveyData)
    const newSurvey = await Survey.create(surveyData);
    newSurvey.save()
    .then(() => {
        res.status(200).json({ message: 'Survey saved successfully' })
    })
    .catch((err) => {
      console.log(err)
        res.status(500).json({ message: 'Error saving survey' });
        });
  });

module.exports = router;
```

error: ValidationError: Survey validation failed: message: Path `message` is required., address: Path `address` is required., phoneNumber: Path `phoneNumber` is required., email: Path `email` is required., nationality: Path `nationality` is required., gender: Path `gender` is required., name: Path `name` is required.

Comment: @user1290323 I'm using the latest version

Comment: Let's see the network request in chrome

Comment: It appears that the error is coming from mongodb, can you show us the model schema. What is the output of your log... `const surveyData = req.body;
    console.log(surveyData)`

Comment: @user1290323 it prints undefined

Comment: Can you provide us with the model schema?

Comment: In the front end, what happens when you `console.log(newSurvey)`

Comment: Are you using bodyParser to parse the data coming in from your front-end? For example, `app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: true} ));` and `app.use(express.json());` will allow you to parse json or standard url encoded forms.